# Error: expected primary-expression before 'x'

Tags: c++

Can you please help me with my coding issue?
I have marked the three line that give me the same error, the title of the problem. I have included most of the other code of the program to help you see what I am trying to do, sorry if it is cluttered.
Yes, the code is unfinished but I want to figure out this problem before finishing it.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fractions.h"


int main()
{
    cs231::Fraction x{1, 2};
    cs231::Fraction y{4, 8};

    if (x.equals(y))
    {
        std::cout << "1/2 = 4/8\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "1/2 != 4/8\n";
    }

    cs231::Fraction z{2,3};
    cs231::Fraction w = x.add(z);
    cs231::Fraction v = x.subtract(z);
    cs231::Fraction u = x.multiply(z);
    cs231::Fraction t = x.divide(z);

    std::cout << "1/2 + 2/3 = " << w.to_string() << "\n";
    std::cout << "1/2 - 2/3 = " << v.to_string() << "\n";
    std::cout << "1/2 * 2/3 = " << u.to_string() << "\n";
    std::cout << "1/2 / 2/3 = " << y.to_string() << "\n"; */

    std::cout << x.to_string() << "\n";
    std::cout << y.to_string() << "\n";
}

----------

    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include "fractions.h"

    namespace cs231
    {
        //default condtructor
        Fraction::Fraction()
        {
            this->n = 0;
            this->d = 1;
        }

        //regular constructor
        Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d)
        {
            if (d < 1)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error{"bad denominator"};
            }

            this->n = n;
            this->d = d;
        }

        std::string Fraction::to_string()
        {
            // convert numbers to strings
            std::stringstream builder;

            builder << this->n << "/";
            builder << this->d;

            std::string result = builder.str();

            return result;
        }

            //member functions
        Fraction add(const Fraction& other)
        {
            int d1, x1, z1, n1;



     /* 1 */     d1= cs231::Fraction x.d * cs231::Fraction z{3};
     /* 2 */     x1= cs231::Fraction x(1) * cs231::Fraction z(2);
     /* 3 */     z1= cs231::Fraction x(2) * cs231::Fraction z(1);

            n1=x1+z1;
            return (n1, d1);

        }

 -----------------------------

    #pragma once
    #include <string>

    namespace cs231
    {
        struct Fraction
        {
            int n;
            int d;

            Fraction(); // default
            Fraction(int n, int d);

            // turns to string
            std::string to_string();

            //member variables
            Fraction add(const Fraction& other);
            Fraction subtract(const Fraction& other);
            Fraction multiply(const Fraction& other);
            Fraction divide(const Fraction& other);

            // true or false value to check if equal
            bool equals(const Fraction& other);
        };
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think these lines should be syntactically correct?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough points to comment, so answering it here.

```
 /* 1 */     d= Fraction x.n * cs231::Fraction z{3};
```

What are you trying to do here with x?
For an example, do you think below will work?

```
d = int x * int y;
```

try compiling it.

Comment: No that will not work. I am trying to use the info from the second number in the struct of X. I have updated the code to try to make it clearer.